# How to sum vector arrays in a list of lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, vector

I want to sum a list of vectors in a list while keeping their dimension and  list structure. How can this be done?

Given a vector
`vecs = [[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]],[[5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7],[8, 8]]]`

and the expected output is
`vecs_sum = [[10,10],[26,26]]`

I tried the following, but it just returns `[]`.

```
vec_sum = []
for inner_list in vec_sum:
  temp = []
  for arr in inner_list:
    temp = [sum(x) for x in zip(arr)]
  vec_sum.append(temp)
```

Comment: Don't you want to be iterating over `vecs`, not `vec_sum`? `vec_sum` is an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
vecs = [[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]],[[5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7],[8, 8]]]
vecs_sum = [list(map(sum, zip(*i))) for i in vecs]
print(vecs_sum)
```

**Output:**

```
[[10, 10], [26, 26]]
```

Comment: Your code seems to give an error : `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: @SurajSubramanian..looks like you have used `list` as a variable name...

Comment: Solution works ok, was not able to find better :-) Upvoted.